# Move div to first p inside another contianer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to move a div from one place to another and place the same div inside first `p` of new container.

I am trying same it is not working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzvdhsq1/1/)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;        
        background: #f0e68c;
    }
    .content{
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 30px 0;
        border: 1px solid #333;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $(".moveForm").appendTo(".box p:first-child");
            $(this).hide(); // Hide move button
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="target" class="box">
        <h1>Target Container</h1>
        <p style="background:red;">one<p>
        <p style="background:blue;">two<p>
    </div>
    <div class="moveForm">
        <h1>Hello World.</h1>

        <p>Click the "Move" button to move this content block first p colored box.</p>
        <button type="button">Move</button>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: If you add jquery it work just fine https://jsfiddle.net/548jLo10/ and use ".box p:first"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".moveForm").appendTo(".box p:first");
        $(this).hide(); // Hide move button
    });
});
```